# localhost:3000 refuses to connect when I run npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, localhost, npm-start

I tried to run my react app on localhost:3000, but it gave me the following errors and localhost refuses to connect.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[3056:0x158008000]      942 ms: Scavenge 66.3 (94.3) -> 57.3 (94.3) MB, 5.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.993, current mu = 0.993) task 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: wasm code commit Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: 0x1049ea9d8 node::Abort() [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 2: 0x1049eab58 node::errors::TryCatchScope::~TryCatchScope() [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 3: 0x104b04384 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 4: 0x104b04318 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 5: 0x105099cdc v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::AllocateForCodeInRegion(v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule*, unsigned long, v8::base::AddressRegion, v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::OptionalLock const&) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 6: 0x10509a970 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::CreateEmptyJumpTableInRegion(int, v8::base::AddressRegion, v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::OptionalLock const&) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 7: 0x105099638 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::AddCodeSpace(v8::base::AddressRegion, v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeAllocator::OptionalLock const&) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 8: 0x10509a780 v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule::NativeModule(v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, v8::internal::VirtualMemory, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::Counters>, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::NativeModule>*) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
 9: 0x10509ccf4 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeManager::NewNativeModule(v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine*, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, unsigned long, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
10: 0x1050a8808 v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine::NewNativeModule(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::wasm::WasmFeatures const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, unsigned long) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
11: 0x105077b54 v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::CreateNativeModule(std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, unsigned long) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
12: 0x105077d1c v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::GetOrCreateNativeModule(std::__1::shared_ptr<v8::internal::wasm::WasmModule const>, unsigned long) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
13: 0x105080380 v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::PrepareAndStartCompile::RunInForeground(v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob*) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
14: 0x10508014c v8::internal::wasm::AsyncCompileJob::CompileTask::RunInternal() [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
15: 0x104a47c08 node::PerIsolatePlatformData::RunForegroundTask(std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::Task, std::__1::default_delete<v8::Task> >) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
16: 0x104a468a0 node::PerIsolatePlatformData::FlushForegroundTasksInternal() [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
17: 0x1051fdc20 uv__async_io [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
18: 0x10520f7e0 uv__io_poll [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
19: 0x1051fe0b0 uv_run [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
20: 0x104a22f40 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
21: 0x1049c37d0 node::Start(int, char**) [/Users/yongyili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node]
22: 0x199079f34 start [/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mockshop@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mockshop@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried the following solution that I found at the following page: [How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)
-npm cache clean --force
-delete node_modules folder
-delete package-lock.json file
-npm install

However, this solution didn't work for me.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: So is there "additional logging output above"?

Comment: what is "additional logging output"?

Comment: What precedes this error message in your console? As your pasted snippet says, "there is likely additional logging output" preceding it.

Comment: I just edited the question description. Can you take a look? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Possibly the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856300/wasm-code-commit-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)?